# My file navigation won't find the right files

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, expo

So i started a new  Expo Go Project and have tried to implement a Css fil in it. But it comes up that the the App.js won't find it.

```js
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Header from './components/Header'
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import About from './pages/About'
import Products from './pages/Products'
import Blog from './pages/Blog'
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
        <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
export default App
```

Both App.js and App.css is in the scr folder.

The error message I get is: Android Bundling failed 13ms
Unable to resolve module ./App.css from C:\Users\jense\1\scr\App.js:

None of these files exist:

- scr\App.css(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
- scr\App.css\index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json)
  1 | import React from 'react'

> 2 | import './App.css'
> |         ^
> 3 | import Header from './components/Header'
> 4 | import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
> 5 | import Home from './pages/Home'

Comment: but this this react not react native